# How can I use [@ref] in a figure context in latex?

Tags: floats, pandoc

I want to add the source of a figure in the caption with [@testQuelle] but it just shows the text "[@testQuelle]" under the picture. What am I doing wrong?

When I try to cite my source outside the figure context it just works fine so my bib is fine (see the code)

sourcecode of Markdown file:

```latex
---
header-includes: |
     \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
---

nach [@testQuelle] ist es..
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{test [@testQuelle] }
    \label{fig:myLabel} 
\end{figure}
```

content of quellen.bib:

```
@online{testQuelle,
  langid = {german},
  title = {eine Test Quelle aus dem Internet},
  url = {https://testQuelle.de},
  abstract = {diese Quelle enthält viele tolle Daten},
  journaltitle = {Quelle},
  urldate = {2019-06-05},
}
```

bash build script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/home/moritz/.cabal/bin/ pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc --bibliography quellen.bib --csl=styles/din1505.csl --filter pandoc-include-code -V hyphens=URL -V breakurl -V papersize=a4paper --from=markdown --output=text.pdf  text.md \
--template template
```

output with -t latex build option

```
nach {[}\protect\hyperlink{ref-testQuelle}{1}{]} ist es..

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{myCaption [@testQuelle] }
    \label{fig:myLabel} 
\end{figure}

\hypertarget{refs}{}
\hypertarget{ref-testQuelle}{}
{[}1{]} \emph{eine Test Quelle aus dem Internet}. URL
\url{https://testQuelle.de}. - abgerufen am 2019-06-05. ---~Quelle
```

see the result. Expected would be "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwzTD.png)" in the caption of the image too:

[image]

Some sucess:

```latex
---
header-includes: |
     \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
nocite: | 
    @testQuelle
---
nach [@testQuelle] ist es..
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{test {[}\protect\hyperlink{ref-testQuelle}{1}{]} }
    \label{fig:myLabel} 
\end{figure}
```

is producing this:

[image: first sucess with new code]

the header-include of `nocite` is necessary because the new ref in the caption is not creating a citation otherwise

A new problem is that the number of the cite in the caption is hard coded 1 now, and wont change by itself

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please turn your code framegents into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce teh issue you describe?

Comment: i tried to edit it to be an mwe

Comment: Compilable (or Working in the MWE acronym) means it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: but i use pandoc with a template so there is no ```\documentclass``` and ```\end{document}``` in my Markdown file or what do you mean?

Comment: @MoritzVierneusel: You could do `pandoc -t latex` to convert to a pandoc-generated LaTeX. But as I get your problem, `pandoc` treats everything inside a LaTeX environment or a command _inside Markdown_ as an escape to LaTeX. Thus, no markdown parsing in done in those parts. If you find out, to what LaTeX reference name your pandoc reference is compiled to, you could use that. Else, I am thrilled for a real answer to your question.

Comment: I think you named the problem, but maybe there is a posibility to force markdown parsing?! I will add the latex output to the question, but i already tried to use the compiled code in the figure with no success

Comment: Not that I am aware of a way to do it. Now, a minor thing about reference hardcoding: if you replace the copied reference `{[}\protect\hyperlink{ref-testQuelle}{1}{]}` with `\cite{testQuelle}`, would it work? You might need to switch to completely LaTeX-based bibliography though, i.e., using `\cite{reference}` everywhere in text or ensure `[@reference]` gets compiled to it.

Comment: ```\cite{testQuelle}``` gives me ```[?]``` no matter if inside or outside the figure, but i think the problem may be that the ```[@testQuelle]``` is creating the cite from the ```quellen.bib``` so there is no cite entry at all

Comment: cross post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177915/214446

Comment: Here's [a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178931/10110578) to solve this problem.